# Case insensitively removing a substring, efficiently

Tags: java, beginner, strings, programming-challenge

I am going through the CodingBat exercises for Java. I have just completed [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p192570) one:

> Given two strings, `base` and `remove`, return a version of the `base` string where all instances of the `remove` string have been removed (not case sensitive). You may assume that the remove string is length 1 or more. Remove only non-overlapping instances, so with `xxx` removing `xx` leaves `x`.

I wanted to try using a `StringBuilder` to solve this because I have not done so before. Here is my code:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove){

    String removeLo = remove.toLowerCase();
    String removeHi = remove.toUpperCase();

    int rL = remove.length();

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(base);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int j = s.indexOf(remove, i);

        if (j < 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            s.delete(j, j + rL);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int j = s.indexOf(removeLo, i);

        if (j < 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            s.delete(j, j + rL);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int j = s.indexOf(removeHi, i);

        if (j < 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            s.delete(j, j + rL);
        }
    }   
    return s.toString();
}
```

The code repeats the for loop 3 times in order to search for the unaltered, lower case, and upper case versions of `remove`. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to reduce this down to one `for` loop, and is that practical (with good readability)?
2. The test strings involve digits. Is it problematic to be 'converting' these to lower and/or upper cases? Should I deal with those before testing the alphabetic strings?
3. The following test cases are the ones that require all three `for` loops:

   ```
   withoutString("xxx", "x")
   withoutString("1111", "1")
   withoutString("MkjtMkx", "Mk")
   withoutString("Hi HoHo", "Ho")
   ```

   The rest of the tests work without the first `for` loop (unaltered `remove`). The second two make sense, because the `remove` string uses upper and lower case, but the first two don't follow this. I have used the debugger in Eclipse but I still can't figure this out. Can you please explain?

Comment: Are you allowed to use regular expressions? I'm sure it will be much easier that way.

Comment: @GiantTree How could I make use of a string within a regular expression statement?

Comment: Simply pass it as the regular expression. The ' Pattern` class takes care of managing the regular expression and the `Matcher` class makes sure that only non-overlapping Strings are matched. It all comes down to one line: `return Pattern.compile(remove, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(base).replaceAll("");`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions make your life really easy when solving such exercises:

```
public static String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
    return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(remove), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(base).replaceAll("");
}
```

I explain this code a little:

1. `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(remove), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`: Creates a regular expression pattern containing the string you want to have removed. `Pattern.quote(remove)` takes care of special characters that may be interpreted as a regular expression (such as: `*, \, +, (), [] etc.`). The flag `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` makes sure, that the case of the characters don't matter.
2. `.matcher(base)`: returns a `Matcher` that holds all matches of the regular expression in the string `base`.
3. `.replaceAll("");`: replaces all matches that have been found with an empty string, effectively removing them.

You may have noticed, that I made this method `static` because it does not access any fields or methods that are non-static. This is always advised unless it really needs to be non-static for some reason.

Comment: Without `Pattern.quote` it breaks whenever there's special char in `remove`.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to take care about the case when there is a real regular expression passed as an argument. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you haven't solved the challenge.  There are two problems:

1. You handle the cases where…

   - the `base` string contains the `remove` string verbatim,
   - the `base` string contains an UPPERCASE version of `remove`,
   - the `base` string contains a lowercase version of `remove`.

   However, you fail to remove anything if the `base` string contains a wEiRDcASE version of `remove`.
2. Bad things happen because you are doing the removal in multiple passes.  For example, I expect the result of `withoutString("Vacuum the carcarpetpet", "carpet")` to be `"Vacuum the carpet"`.  However, your code would produce `"Vacuum the "`.

   **Performing string substitutions in multiple passes is nearly always the wrong thing to do.**  Here is [another example of this type of bug](/a/57185/9357).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the variables aren't named properly. `rl` and `s` aren't intuitive at all. Don't hesitate to write longer variable names, it will be very helpful if you ever want to understand your code easily in the future. Same goes for your method name, `withoutString` isn't clear enough. Your method removes all occurence of a `String`  in another `String`. So you might want to consider `removeAllOccurences` or something like that as a method name.

Next, as @200_success pointed out, your code has flaws. Whenever you see that you wrote 2 (or more in this case) loops with the almost same code, you should wonder if there's another way you could do it.

I'm not sure my method is the most efficient, but I think it can lead you to a good path.

```
private static String removeAllOccurences(String base, String remove){

    StringBuilder baseLowered = new StringBuilder(base.toLowerCase());
    String removeLowered = remove.toLowerCase();
    StringBuilder baseToModify = new StringBuilder(base);

    int removeLength = remove.length();
    int removeIndex = baseLowered.indexOf(removeLowered);

    while(removeIndex != -1){
        baseToModify = baseToModify.delete(removeIndex,removeIndex + removeLength);
        baseLowered = baseLowered.delete(removeIndex,removeIndex + removeLength);
        removeIndex = baseLowered.indexOf(removeLowered);
    }

    return baseToModify.toString();
}
```

I use `baseLowered` and `removeLowered` in order to find the indexes of the `remove` but I keep another `StringBuilder` named `baseToModify` to remove the words. The index to remove will be the same wether the `base` is lowered or not. You also need to remove from `baseLowered` in order not to find the same index again and again.

I'm not sure if I'm clear in my explanations, it's been awhile since I reviewed something ;) If you don't understand something, don't hesitate to comment and I will answer as fast as I can.

Comment: I understand that my code has flaws, please read my original post. Regarding the string name `withoutString`, this is something set by the challenge creator, so that is nothing to do with my reasoning. However your point about more logical variables names makes sense so I will put this into practise from now on. I like how your version was done with `StringBuilder` and I will look to use it more and more often in the future, it certainly makes sense in this example, it's just a case of me learning it.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude in my review, I'm sorry if it felt this way!

Comment: Not at all, I just wanted to be clear that I was aware the `for` loops were dumb :)